# How to deal with imported class and use them in Parent Class

Tags: c#, forms

How do i rename an imported class so i can access it.Below is the code of the Class with a different name space which was imported and the Class of the one i am working on respectively.Should i just change the name space?

```
namespace FaultTreeSelectionAsistant
{
   public partial class Astra : Form
   {
      public Astra()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
}


namespace THE_HELP
{
    public partial class MainPanel : Form
    {
       public MainPanel()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void MainPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give an alias to a namespace or a class like this :

```
using FTSA = FaultTreeSelectionAsistant;
using FtsaAstra = FaultTreeSelectionAsistant.Astra;
```

Comment: after i did that i got this  Warning 1 Error creating 'Namespace provider' object. and then hangs

Comment: Could you provide more about the problem? which `using` did you used and on which line the error occurred? It would be nice if you can include that line or block of code.

Comment: `using FTSA = FaultTreeSelectionAsistant;
using FtsaAstra = FaultTreeSelectionAsistant.Astra;
using FtsaCommonCauseFailure = FaultTreeSelectionAsistant.CommonCauseFailure;
using FaultTreeSelectionAsistant;



namespace THE_HELP
{
    public partial class MainPanel : Form
    {
    

        public MainPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void MainPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CommonCauseFailure ccf = new CommonCauseFailure();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Use . (dot) to delimit namespaces in a declaration :

In MainPanel, you can declare:

```
FaultTreeSelectionAsistant.Astra astra;
```

To avoid expliciting the namespace name, you can import it with a `using` declarative:

```
using FaultTreeSelectionAsistant;
```

Please consult MSDN for a complet description of [what are namespaces and how to use them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use intellisense:

Just write the class name for example `Astra`, mouse hover and see the option:

[image]